# Frame overwrites the button?

Tags: javascript, html, iframe, greasemonkey, frame

```
dv = document.createElement('div'); // create dynamically div tag
    dv.setAttribute('id', "lyr1"); // give id to it
    dv.className = "top"; // set the style classname
    // set the inner styling of the div tag
    dv.style.position = "absolute";
    // set the html content inside the div tag
    dv.innerHTML = "<input id='serialize01' type='button' value='Serialize' onClick='objSerializeDOM.createXML(),objSerializeDOM.disableSerialize()'/>";

    // finally add the div id to your form
    document.body.insertBefore(dv, document.body.firstChild);
```

I am using this javascript code to put a button on every page of my domain.I achieve this using **GreaseMonkey4IE plugin for IE**.But the problem now is that it's not working for the web pages having frames.

file1.html

```
<html>
  <head>
   <title></title>
  </head>

  <frameset rows="50%,50%">
  <frame src="friends.html">

  </frameset>

</html>
```

main.html

```
<html>
<head>
<title>Joe and Jackie's friends</title>
</head>

<frameset cols="25%,75%">
  <frame src="file1.html">
</frameset>

</html>
```

friends.html

```
<html>
<head>
<title></title>
</head>
<body bgcolor="#ccffff">

Joe's friend<br>
<b>Bill</b>

</body>
</html>
```

When I deploy the above files using tomcat, the button is not showing up.
To deploy :
1.I copied all three html files above and pasted'em inside a fodler named say folder1.
2.Copied folder1 inside webapps folder in tomcat directory.
3.Registered my .js file for domain(i.e,) localhost in GreaseMonkey4IE
4.Hit the URL from browser(**IE8**) i.e, http://localhost:8080/file1.html (button shows)
5.Hit the URL from browser i.e, http://localhost:8080/main.html (button does not show up.)
I guess whenever there are frames in the web page, it seems the button appended on the web-page get overwritten by the frame . :(

**Any idea???**
**Is it by any way possible to get my button displayed ??**
Thanks a lot.

Comment: GreaseMonkey script is executed on framed page, or not? Can you put alerts or console output for check. If it's executed: what times count is executed: one time, three, four. Check window.location.href value for each time GM script is executed. Does GreaseMonkey understand _localhost:8080_ as same domain as _localhost_ ?

Comment: GreaseMonkey4IE has been defunct for a long while (and you're the only one who asks SO questions about it).  Consider switching to something that still has support, like [IE7Pro](http://www.ie7pro.com/) (which works on IE8, too).

Comment: @ Andrew There is no problem executing GreaseMonkey script on framed page. GM script executes exactly once.No, localhost:8080 is not understood as same domain as localhost by GM4IE, it stopped working as soon as I edited the domain.And finally window.location.href gives the first URL I hit, as my script is also running only once.

Comment: I'm not sure, but in pages with FRAMESET adding elements to body it's not possible. For your task, when loaded page with FRAMSET, you must enumerate all frames, get document of each frame, and insert your button on each frame->document. Or you must use IFRAME's instead of FRAME's

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
var frameSet = document.getElementsByTagName("frameset");
    if (frameSet[0] != null && frameSet[0] != undefined) {
        var frame = document.createElement('FRAME');
        frame.id = "frame1";
        frame.name = "frame1";
        frame.src = "";
        frameSet[0].rows = "40," + frameSet[0].rows;
        frameSet[0].insertBefore(frame, frameSet[0].firstChild);
        var frame = document.frames[0];
        var currentDocument = frame.document;
        currentDocument.write('<html> <body> <INPUT TYPE="submit" name="btn101" value="Serialize" onClick=""/>  <input id="checkbox101" type="checkbox">IncludeValues</input><br> </body> </html>');
```

I tried the above code and it worked for me.
This time I created a new frame and then put my button on it and finally added the frame as the first frame.
The code provided in the question will work only in case where the web pages don't have any frame.

Answer (score 0):

If you can use php you may find it much easier to add in a global button by calling a php include script. I switched from using JavaScript to php and found it cleaned up allot of browsers problems because the buttons are added during page render instead of by the browsers on the users end.

example

```
<?php include('demo.php'); ?>
```

then just put your raw html in a file called "demo.php" then upload it in the same file and see if it works :)

good luck!

Comment: PHP is no option for me.Thanks though.